# Can my provider detect p2p traffic if I use OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, p2p

Sorry, may be this question is stupid, but I need to know this.

Can my provider detect **p2p** traffic if I use OpenVPN or some other VPN protocols?

Comment: Also see: http://superuser.com/questions/407124/could-local-isp-capture-my-location-whenever-i-launch-a-vpn-to-a-vpn-server, http://superuser.com/questions/609406/if-one-uses-a-vpn-can-the-isp-still-see-or-know-what-exact-urls-one-visits-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configure your system correctly, no, at least not definitively. the traffic passing through their system will be fully encrypted (including header data), so they cannot read the data. there are still several attacks based on patterns of data transmission and reception that could give them hints as to what you are doing with your connection (timing of flows, size of responses, etc), but no clear insight, as long as your encryption and configuration are being used correctly. be particularly careful of DNS query leakage. do not configure to use your ISP DNS servers, and make sure ALL traffic off your net goes through the VPN.